Gstreamer v1.24 fails to play video from MPEG2-TS with KLV metadata stream: Failed to parse PES metadata access units
I can't play a MPEG2-TS stream with KLV (MPEG-TS elementary stream with packet identifier PID 0x28)
This command works for Gstreamer version 1.22.12, but not for the latest release of Gstreamer, version 1.24.8. The video doesn't play, and an error is shown. In the future, it would also be nice to get the klv metadata (e.g. appsink) but this is not the main issue here.
Would anyone have any advice, or what I can do to get it working for gstreamer? Note: it does work for Gstreamer 1.22.12.
My command
GST_DEBUG=3 ./gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=reproducible.ts  ! decodebin ! autovideosink

or alternatively
GST_DEBUG=3 ./gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=reproducible.ts ! tsdemux ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Error
tsdemux tsdemux.c:3412:parse_pes_metadata_frame: Failed to parse PES metadata access units

The test file can be downloaded from google drive.
Full logs
GST_DEBUG=3 ./gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/Users/user/Desktop/reproducible-mpeg2ts-klv.ts ! decodebin ! autovideosink
0:00:00.009753583 88548    0x15800c1e0 WARN            GST_REGISTRY gstregistrybinary.c:552:gst_registry_binary_check_magic: Binary registry magic version is different : 1.23.90 != 1.3.0
0:00:03.405690292 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                 default gstjackloader.c:187:gst_jack_load_library: Could not open library libjack.0.dylib, dlopen(libjack.0.dylib, 0x0009): tried: 'libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/lib/../lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/lib/../libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/lib/../../lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/gstreamer-1.0/../libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/gstreamer-1.0/../../lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/gstreamer-1.0/../lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0-1.1.24.7/libexec/gstreamer-1.0/../../../lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libjack.0.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user/gstreamer/lib/libjack.0.dylib' (no such file)
0:00:03.405739125 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                 default gstjack.c:108:plugin_init: Failed to load jack library
0:00:03.439294875 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                 default ges-meta-container.c:237:_set_value:<GESAsset@0x1462c8550> Could not set value on item: format-version
0:00:03.439321542 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                 default ges-meta-container.c:237:_set_value:<GESAsset@0x1462c85d0> Could not set value on item: format-version
0:00:03.439334459 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                 default ges-meta-container.c:237:_set_value:<GESAsset@0x1462c8650> Could not set value on item: format-version
0:00:03.440124500 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN               structure gststructure.c:2371:priv_gst_structure_parse_fields: Failed to find delimiter, r=mimetype
0:00:03.447295000 88550    0x1157ed0f0 WARN                  ladspa gstladspa.c:509:plugin_init:<plugin206> no LADSPA plugins found, check LADSPA_PATH
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:04.032324333 88548    0x12700cea0 FIXME              glcontext gstglcontext.c:1956:gst_gl_context_request_config:<glcontextcocoa1> does not support requesting a config
0:00:04.032344208 88548    0x12700cea0 WARN               glcontext gstglcontext.c:1299:gst_gl_context_create_thread:<glcontextcocoa1> failed to request config gst-gl-context-config, platform=(GstGLPlatform)GST_GL_PLATFORM_CGL, alpha-size=(int)8, depth-size=(int)0, stencil-size=(int)0, red-size=(int)8, green-size=(int)8, blue-size=(int)8, samples=(int)0, sample-buffers=(int)0;
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayCocoa\)\ gldisplaycocoa0";
Missing element: KLV Metadata decoder
0:00:04.044863208 88548    0x159039120 ERROR                tsdemux tsdemux.c:3412:parse_pes_metadata_frame: Failed to parse PES metadata access units
0:00:04.044871333 88548    0x159039120 WARN              mpegtsbase mpegtsbase.c:1781:mpegts_base_loop:<tsdemux0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:04.044873833 88548    0x159039120 WARN              mpegtsbase mpegtsbase.c:1781:mpegts_base_loop:<tsdemux0> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/mpegtsdemux/mpegtsbase.c(1781): mpegts_base_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:04.044940166 88548    0x159039180 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin2.c:4737:gst_decode_bin_expose:<decodebin0> error: no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: KLV Metadata (meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true)

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
../gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c(4737): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: KLV Metadata (meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true)

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Freeing pipeline ..

Attempted solution
Using decodebin caps, e.g. GST_DEBUG=3 ./gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=reproducible.ts ! decodebin 'caps=video/x-raw(ANY); meta/x-klv' ! autovideosink to ignore the klv data. This doesn't change any errors.
